# Test if post-exposure value is different from pre-exposure value in a follow-up adjusted for baseline analysis using a cumulative probability model?

Tags: ancova, ordered-logit

I'm trying to conduct a follow-up adjusted for baseline analysis using ANCOVA with a proportional odds model (using the `rms` package in R). After fitting the model I am able to obtain an estimate of the predicted median post-exposure value (and confidence intervals) in each exposure strata when the baseline value is fixed.

Is there a way to test if these estimated post-exposure values are different than the fixed baseline? My hunch is that I need to transform the fixed baseline value so it's on the same scale as the linear predictors.

Example:

```r
library(rms)

# sample data
x <- sample(c(0, 1), size = 50, replace = T)
pre <- rnorm(n = 50, mean = 75, sd = 10)
post <- rnorm(n = 50, mean = 72, sd = 10) - x*10

mock <- data.frame(x = x, 
                   pre = pre, 
                   post = post)

# model
dd <- datadist(mock)
options(datadist = "dd")
fit <- orm(post ~ x + pre, data = mock)
med <- function(x) Quantile(fit)(0.5, x)

Predict(fit, x, pre = 75, fun = med)
#>   x pre     yhat    lower    upper
#> 1 0  75 67.76541 64.16905 71.88874
#> 2 1  75 61.47607 59.66793 64.50384
#> 
#> Response variable (y):  
#> 
#> Limits are 0.95 confidence limits
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

In this example, I've fit a model based on the simulated data and have predicted the median post-exposure value across treatment strata when the pre-exposure value is fixed at 75. I now want to test if those estimates are different than 75:

$H_0: post = 75$
$H_A: post \neq 75$

The goal in this case is not only to comment on whether there is a difference in the post-exposure values between the treatment groups but also to assess if there was a change at follow-up compared to baseline.